# Objetos literales sin poder encontrar la vuelta

Tags: javascript

Sigo con este ejercicio.
Consigna

**En base a las definiciones técnicas tomadas con el equipo deberás declarar la variable autos. Esta debe contener los siguientes vehículos:
El primer auto es un Ford Fiesta Azul, del 2019, con 200 kilómetros, cuyo precio es 150000, disponible en 12 cuotas, con la patente APL123 que no está vendido.
El segundo auto es un Toyota Corolla Blanco, del 2019, 0 kilómetros, cuyo precio es 100000, disponible en 14 cuotas, con la patente JJK116 que no está vendido.
Cada auto debe tener los siguientes atributos: marca, modelo, precio, km, color, cuotas, anio, patente, vendido.**

Mi ejercicio:

```
function Auto(marca, modelo, precio, km, color, cuotas, anio, patente, vendido){
    this.marca=marca
    this.modelo=modelo
    this.precio=precio
    this.km=km
    this.color=color
    this.cuotas=cuotas
    this.anio=anio
    this.patente=patente
    this.vendido=vendido

}
let autos =new Auto (["Ford"],["Fiesta"],150000,200,["Azul"],12,2019,["APL123"],false)

console.log(autos)


module.exports=autos
```

Me tira los siguientes errores:

- La variable "autos" debe contener un array de autos
- La lista debe contener objetos literales con las siguientes propidades: marca, modelo, precio, km, color, cuotas, anio, patente y vendido. Este test prueba el primer elemento.
- Los atributos del objeto auto deben almacenar los siguientes tipos de datos: marca (string), precio (number), km (number), color (string), cuotas (number), anio (number), patente (string) y vendido (boolean). Este test prueba el primer elemento

Estoy realmente confundido, en Visual Studio Code, me lo ejecuta bien pero en la plataforma donde me pide el ejercicio, no me lo acepta.

No logro comprender los errores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pide es un arreglo, no un objeto en la respuesta. Por eso debes insertar cada objeto en ese arreglo.
Además ingresas los strings como arreglos, por eso no coinciden los tipos de datos en el test.

```
function Auto(marca, modelo, precio, km, color, cuotas, anio, patente, vendido){
    this.marca=marca
    this.modelo=modelo
    this.precio=precio
    this.km=km
    this.color=color
    this.cuotas=cuotas
    this.anio=anio
    this.patente=patente
    this.vendido=vendido

}
let autos = []

let auto1 = new Auto ("Ford","Fiesta",150000,200,"Azul",12,2019,"APL123",false)

autos.push(auto1)
console.log(autos)
module.exports=autos
```

Te tocaría ingresar el otro auto para completar el código.